# ¿Puedo deshabilitar estilos del FontDialog?

Tags: c#, .net

Por diversas razones, necesito que todos los estilos, salvo el primero, del FontDialog, se encuentren deshabilitados. O eliminarlos (si es posible). Quiero decir, que por ejemplo, si selecciono Microsoft Sans Serif, que solo se encuentre disponible el estilo de fuente normal. Lo mismo si selecciono  cualquier otro tipo de letra: que sólo se encuentre disponible o habilitado el primer estilo de fuente. ¿Es posible? Estoy intentándolo, y me parece muy complicado. Si es posible, ¿cómo sería posible hacerlo? Un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por como está diseñado [FontDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.fontdialog?view=net-5.0), pareciera que no es trivial y sale más fácil armar tu propio Dialog listando fuentes y una lista hardcoded de tamaños...

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas tu mismo tu propio FontDialog

Comment: De acuerdo. Lo intentaré. Muchas gracias por vuestras aportaciones